# Ruby - What is difference between defining constant using 'const_set' and simple capitalize constant name in the class?

Tags: ruby, constants

I am working on a Rails application where in one class, constants are defined using `const_set constant_name, value`.

I know we can define constants directly in class by just specifying the CAPITALIZE name of the constant with its value like following

```
class A
 RANDOM_CONSTANT = 1
end
```

so what is the difference between defining constants using `const_set` and simply the way I have declared in class `A` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
class A
  RANDOM_CONSTANT = 1
end
```

is simpler to write and read. This should be the preferred way to set a constant.

```
constant_name = 'RANDOM_CONSTANT'
A.const_set(constant_name, 1)
```

will work when the constant name is dynamically generated, and thus more flexible. You'd typically use it only when you want to do some metaprogramming magic.

Other than that, they are equivalent.

Answer (score 5):

I can add to the answer from @amadan that this method, like an others, for example `const_get`, `method_missing`, `define_method` etc is part of tools for meta-programming in ruby.

For example:

1. `#const_get`

Let's say we have such module `Foo` with list of constants: `BOO`, `BAR`, `BAZ`

```rb
module Foo
  BAR = 1
  BAZ = 2
  BOO = 3
end
```

now we need to print all of it, we can do it dynamically or manually:

```rb
def print_dynamically
  Foo.constants.each do |const| 
    p Foo.const_get(const)
  end
end

def print_manually
  p Foo::BAR
  p Foo::BAZ
  p Foo::BOO
end

> print_dynamically
=> 1
=> 2
=> 3

> print_manually
=> 1
=> 2
=> 3
```

2. `#method_missing`

Let's say we have such class `Foo` and we want to add some friendly error catching for `NoMethodError`

```rb
class Foo
  def boo
    puts 'boo'
  end

  def method_missing(method_name)
    puts "sorry, method: ##{method_name} not defined."
    puts "Here is a list of public methods:"
    # here we take all defined public methods from class Foo except `#method_missing`
    p public_methods(false).reject { |n| n == :method_missing } 
  end
end

> foo = Foo.new
> foo.boo
=> boo
> foo.bar
=> sorry, method: #bar not defined.
=> Here is a list of public methods:
=> [:boo]
```

3. `#define_method`

Let's say we need to define some list of simple(or not) methods, and we don't want to just copy-paste it:

instead of:

```rb
class Foo
  def foo
    puts "foo"
  end
  def boo
    puts "boo"
  end
  def bar
    puts "bar"
  end
end

> foo.foo
=> foo
> foo.boo
=> boo
> foo.bar
=> bar
```

you can simply write it in his way:

```rb
class Foo
  %i[foo boo bar].each do |method_name|
    define_method(method_name) { puts "#{method_name}" }
  end
end

> foo.foo
=> foo
> foo.boo
=> boo
> foo.bar
=> bar
```

**Summary:** 
From examples below you can see that Ruby provide us a lot of tools for dynamically creation of methods, getting of it, getting of constants and setting of it.

**P.S.**
These is far not all the methods, it's just a few of them, but I think it's enough to show that you can do with meta-programming tools in ruby.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it so well. Really appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there's no difference, so this:

```
class A; end
A.const_set('RANDOM_CONSTANT', 1)
```

is equivalent to:

```
class A
  RANDOM_CONSTANT = 1
end
```